# Access control properties from its dynamically created Event Handler

Tags: c#, winforms, button, event-handling

I am developing a C# `WinForms` application. On the `FormLoad` event, I dynamically create and add to the form 100 buttons without text, but with names like `button1`, `button2` etc. Also, onto these buttons, after their creation, I dynamically link a unique event handler for the `ButtonClick` event. How can I access the button's properties from within the event handler (more specifically the button name)?
If I use this.Name, I get the name of the form, and not the name of the button.

Later Edit: (for those who might wonder here in search of solutions)

```
private void function1()
{
    Button a = new Button();

    a.Name = "button" + (i * j).ToString();
    a.Click += new EventHandler(OnFieldButtonClicked);
}

private void OnFieldButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sender` argument is the event handler encapsulates an instance of the object that has triggered the event:

```
Button button = (Button) sender;
String text = button.Text;
```

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks a bunch!
LE: Yes, I just did not know you can convert the sender into button this way. :)

Comment: +1 With this, you don't need to add a unique button handler.  It might help the answer to include the full method definition.

Comment: I added it after your response. I mentioned that.